# How to increment an integer while passing a multi-line string to a command using "Here tag" in bash

Tags: bash, increment, multiline, multilinestring

I have a piece of code that looks similar to this:

```
index=SOME_INTEGER
SOME_COMMAND <<EOF
subcommand1
${index} subsubcommand1
subcommand2
$((${index}+1)) subsubcommand2
subcommand3
$((${index}+2)) subsubcommand3
subcommand4
$((${index}+3)) subsubcommand4
subcommand5
$((${index}+4)) subsubcommand5
EOF
```

This method of manually adding one more to ${index} for each new subcommand is quite tedious, and not very practical if i need to rearrange the order/delete lines (the subcommand1 line must precede the subsubcommand1 line and the indexes must be given from lowest to highest), so i was wandering if there was a simple way to increment ${index} between <<EOF and EOF without referencing an exact number, or if there was an alternative way to pass the subcommands to SOME_COMMAND that would allow for this.

I have tried to give various commands like the following but they have not worked:

```
$((index=$((index+1))))
$((index=index+1))
$((index+=1))
$((index++))
```

Comment: Do you _really_ need to use a heredoc for this as opposed to, say, a process substitution with the same output?

Comment: BTW, `++input` is probably more relevant than `input++`, since you want the value actively being used to reflect the update. Will be a minute before I can sit down and test anything, though, and I'm much more confident in the process substitution approach.

Comment: You could probably even stick with the postincrement if you changed the initial `${index}` to `$((index++))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: If you switch from a postincrement to a preincrement, your original code works. That is:

```
SOME_COMMAND() { cat; }
 
index=5
 
SOME_COMMAND <<EOF
subcommand1
${index} subsubcommand1
subcommand2
$((++index)) subsubcommand2
subcommand3
$((++index)) subsubcommand3
subcommand4
$((++index)) subsubcommand4
subcommand5
$((++index)) subsubcommand5
EOF
```

properly emits as output:

```
subcommand1
5 subsubcommand1
subcommand2
6 subsubcommand2
subcommand3
7 subsubcommand3
subcommand4
8 subsubcommand4
subcommand5
9 subsubcommand5
```

---

If that *didn't* work, though, the easy, surefire thing to do here would be to write a function that generates your desired input. You can then either expand that function into a heredoc or herestring (if SOME_COMMAND needs its input to be seekable), or use it directly as a process substitution (if SOME_COMMAND only needs its input to be streamable).

```
input_for_SOME_COMMAND() {
  local index mainCommand
  index=$1; shift || return
  for arg; do
    printf '%s\n' "$arg" "$((index++)) sub$arg"
  done
}

SOME_COMMAND <<<"$(input_for_SOME_COMMAND 1 subcommand{1,2,3,4,5})"
```

See this working in an online sandbox at https://ideone.com/XOUauQ